# Не работает алгоритм доминирующих матричных стратегий

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы

```
import functools

n = int(input())
m = int(input())

lst1 = [list(map(int,input().split())) for i in range(n)]
m1 = 0
n1 = 0
while m1 != m and n1 != n:
    m1 = m
    n1 = n
    i = 0
    while i != n:
        j = i + 1
        while j != n:
            if functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x and y,map(lambda p, q: p <= q,lst1[i],lst1[j]),True):
                del lst1[i]
                #n -= 1
            elif functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, map(lambda p, q: p >= q, lst1[i],lst1[j]), True):
                del lst1[j]
                n -= 1
            else:
                j += 1
            i +=1
        i = 0
        while i != m:
            j = i +1
            while j != m:
                a = [lst1[k][i] for k in range(n)]
                b = [lst1[k][j] for k in range(n)]
                if functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, map(lambda p, q: p >= q,a,b),True):
                    for _ in range(n):
                        del lst1[_][i]
                    m -= 1
                elif functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, map(lambda p, q: p <= q,a,b),True):
                    for _ in range(n):
                        del lst1[_][j]
                    m -= 1
                else:
                    j += 1
                i += 1
            for i in lst1:
                print(i)
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: как решили что не работает?

Comment: С примерами 4 на 4 выдаёт ошибку о выходе за пределы массива, расширение не помогло.